# Put Activation Code into Deep Security Manager using API - 500 error code

Tags: deepsecurity

How to provide DSM with Activation Code using API or Command Line tool?

Following code gives error code 500:

`curl --insecure --cookie 'sID=00B5B7ECD2FA3B28FB23FD094BCC76BE' --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --data '{"UpdateLicenseActivationCodesRequest": {"activationCodes": ["<activation code>"]}}' https://<ip address>:4119/rest/license?update=True`

Respond:
{"error":{"message":"HTTP 500 Internal Server Error"}}

Any ideas?
P.S.
I am using TMDS 12.0 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Could be that this error is because TMDS is already has correct Activation Code

Comment: Already having the activation code is not something that is expected to cause a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

That request appears to be correct. Therefore I recommend you try it again removing the "update=True" part. That is not needed to add a new activation code, and adding that part to the request triggers some additional functionality before the activation code is added, which could be the source of this error.

P.S. I work in R&D for Trend Micro

Comment: Same problem, but now  it shows

{"error":{"message":"Internal server error"}}192

Command is
curl --silent --insecure --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --cookie sID=6A97BE01926F1B1E2E6156A1AE48B3EC --data '{"UpdateLicenseActivationCodesRequest": {"activationCodes": ["<activation code>"]}}' https://10.15.184.160:4119/rest/license
P.S. I work for Trend Micro as Sales Engineer

Comment: Do you have logs access? It's hard to know what's causing this without more info. You might need a support case, or if you're in slack, you can share more detail in the channel for api support there.

Comment: This is not a problem with my particular TMDS. I have created product cloud vApp. Following command gives same result:
curl --silent --insecure --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  --data '{"dsCredentials": {"userName": "MasterAdmin", "password": "trendmicro"}}' https://10.28.56.175:4119/rest/authentication/login
Result: A577EAFEE5C41D453172E89E29EF0F04

Comment: Update license
curl --silent --insecure --request POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" --cookie sID=A577EAFEE5C41D453172E89E29EF0F04 --data '{"UpdateLicenseActivationCodesRequest": {"activationCodes": ["AP-J7CB-N27JJ-4UZ4K-TKFZ4-KBCEB-ZJBKF"]}}' https://10.28.56.175:4119/rest/license
Result: {"error":{"message":"Internal server error"}}
You can check it out yourself

Comment: The problem is with the activation code you are using, not the API, as far as I can tell. The code is valid (or valid looking), but the module associated with it does not match anything the API expects, so there's an error. Other codes are working find in the API. Is there something special or new about the code type?